# mediaelement.js fullscreen overlay

Tags: mediaelement.js

Is there a way to create an overlay (for text, captions, etc) when the mediaelement.js player goes into fullscreen? This is easy to do when the player is embedded on a page, but I can't get an overlay to show up once it goes fullscreen.

Answer (score 1):

I've not had success with placing HTML elements over the video when in full screen. When in Full screen on some devices I seem to not have anything of the DOM showing. The tablet starts playing the video natively without the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that's the way it's designed -- no DOM manipulation on fullscreen.